# How do I install libXfixes.so.3 in Ubuntu 13.04 64bit?

Tags: libraries

A program reports this error:

> Error libXfixes.so.3: cannot open shared object file

How can I resolve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Close-voter(s): Why do you think this is a bug?

Comment: Short answer: install the libxfixes3 package. How I found out about it? See the link in my comment above.